# Why fmap f xs = pure f <*> xs?

Tags: haskell, applicative

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
       pure :: a -> f a
       (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

> "pure" plays two roles:
>   * The degenerate case when you have a
>   0-ary function, kind of.
>   * fmap f xs = pure f <*> xs

I don't understand why

```
fmap f xs = pure f <*> xs
```

I mean `pure` should take any `a` and return `f a`. But what does `pure f` do? Even `pure (f <*> xs)` makes sense to me.

Comment: `pure (f <*> xs)` would be an odd expression to see, as it would imply adding a new minimal applicative layer on top of an existing applicative functor. What are you thinking it means?

Comment: I think `(f <*> xs)` will apply `f` to each element in `xs`, then `pure` will take it as a whole and then return `f a`.

Comment: Applying `f` to each element in `xs` is what `fmap` does. `<*>` is for combining the contexts of a stateful value and a function which is *also* stateful. Carrying the `fmap` analogy for lists specifically, `<*>` would apply every function in a list to every element of `xs`, where `fmap` applies a single function to every element of a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a concrete example would be illustrative. Take the list applicative. `<*>` applies *each* function from its left operand to *each* value from its right:

```
fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
```

And `pure` wraps a value in a singleton list:

```
pure (+ 1) = [(+ 1)]
```

So `pure f <*> xs` = `fmap f xs`, because `<*>` applies each function—**of which there happens to be only one**—to each value, while `fmap` applies one function to each value:

```
pure (+ 1) <*> [1, 2, 3]
=
[(+ 1)] <*> [1, 2, 3]
=
[f x | f <- [(+ 1)], x <- [1, 2, 3]]
=
[(+ 1) x | x <- 1, 2, 3]
=
[x + 1 | x <- 1, 2, 3]
=
[2, 3, 4]


fmap (+ 1) [1, 2, 3]
=
[(+ 1) x | x <- [1, 2, 3]]
=
[x + 1 | x <- [1, 2, 3]]
=
[2, 3, 4]
```

This is also how the `<$>` and `<*>` operators work together to apply a multi-argument function over the results of multiple actions, e.g.:

```
(*) <$> [1..5] <*> [1..5]
=
((*) <$> [1..5]) <*> [1..5]
=
[(1 *), (2 *), (3 *), (4 *), (5 *)] <*> [1..5]
=
[ (1 *) 1, (2 *) 1, (3 *) 1, (4 *) 1, (5 *) 1
, (1 *) 2, (2 *) 2, (3 *) 2, (4 *) 2, (5 *) 2
, (1 *) 3, (2 *) 3, (3 *) 3, (4 *) 3, (5 *) 3
, (1 *) 4, (2 *) 4, (3 *) 4, (4 *) 4, (5 *) 4
, (1 *) 5, (2 *) 5, (3 *) 5, (4 *) 5, (5 *) 5
]
=
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5
, 2,  4,  6,  8, 10
, 3,  6,  9, 12, 15
, 4,  8, 12, 16, 20
, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
]
```

This could also have been written `pure (*) <*> [1..5] <*> [1..5]`.

`<$>` builds an action (in this case a list) returning (containing) partially applied functions, and `<*>` takes those functions and applies them to arguments. (And if the function takes more than two arguments, then this may also result in partially applied functions, which can be applied to more arguments with another application of `<*>`.)

The same laws hold in other “container-like” applicatives such as `Maybe` or `Either e` (for some `e`), as well as “action-like” applicatives such as `IO`, `Cont r`, or `Async`.

Answer (score 2):

> But what does `pure f` do?

Given, `f :: a -> b`, we obtain `pure f :: f (a -> b)` the last `f` being any applicative functor. This creates a value of the right type to pass as the first argument to

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

> I mean `pure` should take any `a` and return `f a`

Exactly -- in this case the `a` you mention is the function type `a -> b` I mentioned above.